# Unity3D transform like mirror?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

**Hi,** I need help with a big problem.I want to move my object like the picture below. If it is below the screen, it will move itself to the top of the screen and continue to move. How can I do this?

Problem Image:
https://hizliresim.com/Pr2bR5

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you have tried so far? You should take a look at this:  [How do I ask a proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried many ways but it did not work .. Sry for bad question Im new in there

Comment: That doesn't really help us answering your question.

Comment: The problem is; I have objects that are moving downwards. If the objects are below the screen, they will come up again on the screen and continue to move down.I do not know exactly how to tell.Because its hard to explain

Comment: Then post the code of that object moving down the screen

Comment: transform.position = new Vector3 (0f, movement.y, 0f);
movement.y -= moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an empty gameobject at the bottom of your screen. Add a collider(Box collider can do) to it and make it isTrigger and position it just below your screen. Write a code and add it to that empty gameObject with collider to check if any of your object is interacting that collider.

```
void OnTriggerEnter()

if(other.gameObject.tag == "YourTag")

{

   //You can destroy that falling object and create a new one on the top 
   //or simply change its position here
}
```

This will create the effect you want.

Hope this helps! Cheers!